# Rounding a number without using any inbuilt functions and if/else

Tags: java, rounding

> write a function to print floor of a number without using any inbuilt functions, casting  and if else.

I have code here, but just curios to find out is there any other way to find out it efficiently?

```
public class Round 
{
double number=100.211113;
System.out.println(number-(number%1));
}
```

Comment: I assume you are not allowed to use casting as well? Also, is it homework? if yes, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to integer type like(casting):

```
public class Round 
{
double number=100.211113;
long floorPart = (long) number;
System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: We should not use any type casting.